# Expected value of sample standard deviation

Tags: expected-value

I am trying to prove that for i.i.d $X_1,X_2,...$ with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the sample standard variance $S^2=\sum \frac{(X_i-\overline{X})^2}{n-1}$ as expected value $\sigma^2$ where $\overline{X}=\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$.

I understand the proof where you split $(X_i-\overline{X})^2=(X_i-\mu)^2+(\overline{X}-\mu)^2-2(X_i-\mu)(\overline{X}-\mu)$ then take the expected value.

I tried another approach but failed to get the desirable result. I did the following

$$(n-1)E(S^2)=E(\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2)=\sum E(X_i-\overline{X})^2$$
$$=\sum Var(X_i-\overline{X})+[E(X_i-\overline{X})]^2=\sum Var(X_i)+Var(\overline{X})=n(\sigma^2+\sigma^2/n)$$

Can anyone point out the mistake, many thanks

Comment: You want to proof that $E(S^2)=\sigma^2$?

Comment: @callculus42 yes

Comment: So, is the answer compehensible?

Comment: I've made an update. It should fit your question.

Comment: @callculus42 thanks, that is awesome i mismeomrized the formula $Cov(X,Y)=E(X-E(X))E(Y-E(Y))$ receiving 0 covariance. Thanks so much, it is clear that $X_i$ cannot be independent with itself.

Comment: Nice, that all is clear now. Indeed it is $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the proof where you split
> $(X_i-\overline{X})^2=(X_i-\mu)^2+(\overline{X}-\mu)^2-2(X_i-\mu)(\overline{X}-\mu)$
> then take the expected value.

You've ommitted the sigma sign.

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(X_i-\mu)^2-2(\overline X-\mu)(X_i-\mu)+(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right]\right] \quad$

Writing for each summand a sigma sign

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-2(\overline X-\mu)\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)+\sum_{i=1}^n(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right] \quad$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-2(\overline X-\mu)\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)}+n(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right] \quad$

---

*Transforming the blue term*

$\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)=n\cdot \overline X-n\cdot \mu$

Thus $2(\overline X-\mu)\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)}=2(\overline X-\mu)\cdot (n\cdot \overline X-n\cdot \mu)=2n( \overline X- \mu)^2$

---

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-2n( \overline X- \mu)^2+n(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right] \quad$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-n( \overline X- \mu)^2\right] \quad$

I think you can finish. If not, feel free to ask.

**Update**

$$\sum Var(X_i-\overline{X})+\sum [E(X_i-\overline{X})]^2$$

First of all $[E(X_i-\overline{X})]^2=[E(X_i)-E(\overline{X})]^2=[\mu-\mu]^2=0$. Then
$$Var(X_i-\overline{X})=Var(X_i)-2\cdot Cov(X_i,\overline X)+Var(\overline{X})$$

$$=\sigma^2-2\cdot Cov(X_i,\overline X)+\frac{\sigma^2}{n} \qquad (1)$$
Next, the covariance has to be calculated.

$$ Cov(\overline X,X_i)= Cov(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j,X_i) = \frac{1}{n}Cov(\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j,X_i) $$

The assumption is that $X_j's$ are inependent for $i\neq j$. But for i=j we get the variance. Thus $\frac{1}{n}Cov(\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j,X_i)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. Put it in (1) and we obtain

$$=\sigma^2-2\cdot \frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{\sigma^2}{n} =\sigma^2-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

If the sigma signs are regarded, then term has to be multiplied by n:

$$n\sigma^2-\sigma^2=\sigma^2(n-1)=(n-1)E(S^2) \quad \checkmark$$

Your approach is more interesting than it looked like at the first glance.

Comment: I understand this approach but I tried a different approach without splitting $X_i-\overline{X}$ I do not understand where is the mistake in my proof